# Generating Occupied DIVs with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, d3.js

This may seem like a standard question, but none of the Stack threads I've read have covered my needs.

I have a series of nested DIV statements, like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xSEPJ/) (not all CSS included).

I would like to make a simple script to do something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
  //append DIV
  //add identifying class/id
  //change text values
}
```

If it helps, I'm using d3.js in a few visualizations that will accompany these DIVS. I can create those DIVs in d3 if that would be easiest...But I'm not quite sure how I would do that. Any tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a number of divs as children of a different object you can create new elements and then append them to the DOM as children.

Assuming you have a root element on the page

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <p>Everything should follow this</p>
</div>
```

you can then inject any number of elements with some code like this:

```
for (a=0;a<3;a++) {
    var divTag = document.createElement("div"); 
    divTag.id = "div"+a; 
    divTag.setAttribute("align", "center"); 
    divTag.className = "myClass"; 
    divTag.innerHTML = a+" Div tag created dynamically."; 
    document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(divTag); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. This method seems like it works for what it's supposed to do. But I may have asked the question incorrectly. Sorry.

I'm trying to create this DIV multiple times, not append information to a DIV. So eventually, there will be x amount of these containers all with different info. 

If it helps, each one of these containers will represent different devices. Each device will have it's own cost/volts/amp fields.

Comment: the content of the div (where I add the innerHTML) can be anything (including other divs etc) - so your container would repeat. if you want you could also just have a loop that uses document.write to write the repeated HTML structure into the document as the page loads (guess I'm not 100% what you're trying to repeat)

Comment: Ok, I got it to work using your method actually. Just got a bit confused. Thanks for the explanation.